# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, connection-string

I have the following code:

```
            Dim command As New SqlCommand

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerid", textbox1.text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textbox2.text)

        command .Connection = SharedVar.ConnectionString
        SharedVar.ConnectionString.Open()
        command .CommandText = ("SELECT Customer FROM Accounts WHERE CustomerID = @customerid AND Password = @password")
```

When I execute the code I get an error at this position:

```
SharedVar.ConnectionString.Open()
```

The error I receive is: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

SharedVar is a module and in this module there is a variable called ConnectionString. ConnectionString is declared as an SQLConnection. The connection string itself is saved in the application.settings.
The code for SharedVar.ConnectionString is:

```
    Public ConnectionString As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionString)
```

I'm not sure why I am receiving this error since I am already declaring the ConnectionString property at:

```
command .Connection = SharedVar.ConnectionString
```

The connection string saved at My.Settings.ConnectionString is:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Nico\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Database\CustomerDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you have a connection confused with a connectionstring at least as far as variable naming.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to re-evaluate your variable naming as it can be somewhat confusing. Your current code is instantiating an actual `SqlConnection` object as `ConnectionString` (as opposed to just the connection string itself, which is a `String`) :

```
' This creates an actual connection. (My.Settings.ConnectionString is '
' your connnection string) '                                           
Public ConnectionString As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionString)
```

Consider using a pattern like the following one when building your queries :

```
' Build your connection '
Using connection As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionString)
    ' Create your query '
    Dim query = "SELECT Customer FROM Accounts WHERE CustomerID = @customerid AND Password = @password"
    ' Build a command to execute '
    Using command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
         ' Open your connection '
         connection.Open()
         ' Add your parameters ' 
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerid", textbox1.Text)
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textbox2.Text)
         ' Execute your query into a reader '
         Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
               While reader.Read()
                    ' Access your custom information here '
                    Dim customer = reader("Customer")
                    ' Do something else here ... '
               End While
         End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Additionally, it's difficult to tell exactly when some of your properties are being set without seeing the entire snippet of code. This could simply be an instance of your connection string just not being set on your Connection prior to the `Open()` method being called.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried using your code but it still shows the same error. In addition I don't have anymore code before the one I have shown above. I did some more investigating and tried this: textbox1.Text = My.Settings.ConnectionString but textbox1.text is empty even tho in the My.Settings of the program I have manually entered the connection string. This must be the problem but I'm not sure how to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: Is your Connection String stored within your `app.config` file?

Comment: Yes my connection string is stored inside my project folder in a file called app.config

Comment: Have you tried reading it using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("{your-connection-string-name}").ConnectionString`?

Comment: How can I do this ? :/ I tried using your code but I get the error message that ConfigurationManager is not a member of System.Configuration.

Comment: Ensure that you have a reference to `System.Configuration` for your Project (via `Add References...`)

Comment: This is the error I get when executing the code: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `name` property of the `<connectionString>` element in your `app.config` file? The error you are receiving is a null reference exception, which likely means that the `ConfigurationManager` couldn't find the proper connection string.